# Display all content in a group, even to non-members

Tags: organic-groups

I've setup a few Organic Groups. I've created a view to show all of the content (full content) related to the current Group ID in a block. I placed the block onto the group's node page.

The view works fine for members of the group (displays full content). However, I would like to show this same content to non-members of the group as well. Currently, non-members see only titles of the node content related to the group and a link "Request Group Membership". I'd like to continue to display that link, but would like to show the full content of the nodes related to the group, just as members of the group can see. My view is there, but only the titles of the nodes (not linked) display in a list.

Comment: Why did you limit this content type to an OG group? If being member of an OG group is NOT what is required to be able to view the full content of the nodes, how about making such content type NOT depend on OG ? Or is there something missing in the question that would explain that?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It got me thinking and made me realized that I had limited the ability to view body content if not in a group. I'm a little embarrassed, but I realized that I needed to simply turn on the permission: "View Body field" in the OG permissions. Kind of strange that these permissions are not where all of Drupal's normal permissions are! (in the admin area)